# Convert Facebook Video encoded as form data source to direct MP4

Tags: android, facebook, android-videoview

I am using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/videos/

and getting the source of the video, but the source looks like this:

```
https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hvideo-xtp1/v/t43.1792-2/10316008_764387180347436_2106179347_n.mp4?efg=eyJybHIiOjE1MDAsInJsYSI6NDA5Nn0\u00253D&rl=1500&vabr=612&oh=033d719945fb2fce043fb397d83dcc34&oe=553BBF40
```

But when i use this url in Android Video View, i get a Error "Can't play video"

Direct .mp4 links work

So how can I convert the facebook source url to direct .mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading this file by HTML with webview. Check this link i hope it will help you. http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/